# Loop values upto three decimal places within a cell

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim j As Long
 Dim mycell As Range

   For j = 0 To 24

      Range("C12").Value = j

      Range("C93").Formula = "=Round(Sin(C12*pi()/180)*(C84+C88),3)"
      Range("C94").Formula = "=Round((Sin(C12*pi()/180)*(C84+C88))/1000,2)"

      Range("C96").Formula = "=Round(-1*(C80-C93),3)"
      Range("C98").Formula = "=Round((-1*(C80-C93))/1000,2)"

      If Range("C94").Value = Range("C82").Value Then
      MsgBox "The Maximum value of Theta is " & Range("C12").Value & Chr(10)

      Exit For
      End If

    Next
```

I follow a code that loops `j` from 0 to 24.  *Example: 0,1,2,....24*.
But how do I loop from values 0.001 to 0.999, then 1.101.....till 24.

How do I loop up to the desired decimal places?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim j As Long, k As Long

    For k = 0 To 24
        For j = 1 To 999
            Debug.Print k + (j / 1000)
        Next j
    Next k

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an inner loop with something like

```
For j = 0 To 24
   Dim d As Double
   For d = 0 To 0.999 Step 0.001
       Range("C12").Value = j + d 
       ...
   Next d
Next j
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to keep the looping simple and exclude unneeded values inside the loop:

```
Public Sub Test()
   Dim j As Double

   For j = 0.001 To 24 Step 0.001
      If j < 1 Or j > 1.1 Then
         Debug.Print Format(j, "0.000")
      End If
   Next
End Sub
```